# Almacenar números primos previamente verificados en un arreglo

Tags: c, codeblocks

Debo almacenar números primos previamente chequeados si son primos o no, en un arreglo. Puedo verificar si el número es primo o no, pero no sé cómo proceder para almacenar el mismo en un arreglo.

```
int main()
{
    int num,i,cont,a[5],ip;

    printf("ingrese un numero: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    while (num!=0) {
        i=0;
        cont=0;
        for (i=1;i<=num;i++) {
            if (num%i==0) {
                cont=cont+1;
            }
        }
        ip=0;
        if(cont<=2) {
            a[ip]=num; ip++;
            printf("el numero %d fue almacenado en %d",a[ip],ip);
        } else {
            printf("el numero no es primo, por favor ingrese otro numero:");
        }
        printf("ingrese un numero: ");
        scanf("%d",&num);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hasta ahí hice. Intenté con un `while` pero tampoco funciona. No se como ir almacenando número por número después de su verificación.

Comment: Cada vez que encuentras un número y lo vas a guardar, inicializas ip a cero, con lo que siempre lo guarda en la primera posición del array, luego además incrementas ip en uno y muestras en el printf no el que has guardado, sino el siguiente. Y en cada vuelta te pasa lo mismo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto:

```
int num,i,cont,a[5],ip;

ip=0;
if(cont<=2) {
    a[ip]=num; ip++;
    printf("el numero %d fue almacenado en %d",a[ip],ip);
} else {
    printf("el numero no es primo, por favor ingrese otro numero:");
}
```

Debería estar así:

```
int num,i,cont,a[5],ip=0; // <<--- inicializas la variable al declararla

if(cont<=2) { 
    if( ip < 5) // <--- Comprueba que no escribes fuera del array
    {
        a[ip]=num;
        printf("el numero %d fue almacenado en %d",a[ip],ip);
        ip++; // <--- Incrementas su valor después de mostrar el mensaje
    } else {
        printf("el numero %d es primo, pero no se puede almacenar", num);
    }
} else {
    printf("el numero no es primo, por favor ingrese otro numero:");
}
```